# What is the best way to protect a burnished concrete floor during construction?

Tags: concrete, floor, protection

I am doing a new build. The floor is burnished concrete done by High Trowel finish during concrete pour. I need to protect the floor afterwards.
What is the best way to protect a burnished concrete floor during construction?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Plywood. Lay down some sheets and connect them together to stop them shifting if you want to keep them there for a significant period.

Comment: +1 and for belt & suspenders, roll cardboard (like Ramboard), then plywood. Expensive combo, but pretty follproof.